# how to fill a value user selected in the picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads

I am new to sfdc .I got a requirement like when user selects any option in the picklist,that value has automatically filled in the other standard text field.I tried validation rule and workflows and even i trigger on that lead object but nothing works because text field is a standard text field.My lead object has a recordtype it may leads to any problem.Because company field is required in lead page.Please help

Comment: you can create a formula field for that purpose

Comment: ya tried it before but it cant possible because,I have to get value from picklist it shows error like Channel_Name__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions @Himanshu please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can't access picklist value directly inside the formula field so you need to wrap this around the another function that is **[TEXT](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#TEXT)**  Here is the definition of this function

> Converts a percent, number, date, date/time, or currency type field
>   into text anywhere formulas are used. Also, **converts picklist values**
>   to text in approval rules, approval step rules, workflow rules,
>   escalation rules, assignment rules, auto-response rules, validation
>   rules, **formula fields**, field updates, and custom buttons and links.

So your formula will be

```
TEXT(Channel_Name__c)
```

Comment: Hey i tried like this company is a standard field in lead object.                                        Company  =  TEXT(Channel_Name__c). when i tried create like this it shows me an error like                                                                                                     Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text). But i choose text in formula category. Please help thanks in advance @Himanshu

Comment: Select text as formula instead of boolean

Comment: Ya i select return type text in formula.But it's returned boolean @Himanshu

Comment: ya i tried with formula field with comapny=text(picklist_c).But while creating a lead i got an error like it's mandatory field.So,i have to create a new custom visualforce page right..@Himanshu

Comment: what do you mean by new visualforce page?

Comment: Yes @Himansu because i wrote a trigger on the lead object.But,whenever  i am trying to save the record it shows me an exception.fill all values.Because i think system validations will fire first in sfdc execution right..

Comment: I write a trigger based on lead record type but when creating  a record user has to fill some data in company then only it will work otherwise it is not working..@Himanshu